# PHP - group every 2 parts of a string together in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a long string that is constructed like this:

```
randomstring number     randomstring number     randomstring number
```

I need to group these random strings and numbers together so that I get an array like this:

```
array = [[randomstring, number], [[randomstring, number], [randomstring, number]]
```

I don't know the amount of spaces between the strings and numbers. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Since Edwin Moller's answer I'm now left with this array:

```
Array (46) {

[0] => 
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "string"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "number"
}
[1]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) ""
  [1]=>
  string(7) ""
}

[2] => 
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) ""
  [1]=>
  string(11) ""
}

[3] => 
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) ""
  [1]=>
  string(11) ""
}

[4] => 
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) ""
  [1]=>
  string(11) ""
}
```

The array elements that have 2 empty elements themselves need to be removed.

---

I'll leave it with this solution. It's not elegant at all, but I don't know what these 'empty' strings are. It doesn't respond to whitespace, space, any character test so I used the strlen() function:

```
$str = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $longstring);
$parts = explode(" ", $str);
$nr = count($parts);

for ($i = 0; $i < $nr; $i = $i + 2) {
    if(strlen($parts[$i]) > 20) { // ugly, but it works for now..
        $tmp[] = [$parts[$i], $parts[$i + 1]];
    }
}

// unsetting these elements because they are longer than 30
unset($tmp[0]);
unset($tmp[1]);
unset($tmp[2]);
```

Comment: Will the strings ever have spaces in them?

Comment: @ChrisEvans No, they won't. There is (I think) only 1 space between a string and a number but multiple between a number and the next string.

Comment: split on the number, giving you `["rand num"],["rand num"]`, then split each of those new strings on the space, for `[["rand",num],["rand",num]]`

Comment: @MarcB Could you perhaps give me some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$longstring = "randomstring1 1001     randomstring2 205 randomstring3 58";
// First, take care of the multiple spaces.
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $longstring);

// split in parts on space
$parts = explode(" ",$str);
$nr = count($parts);

$tmp = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i=$i+2){
  $tmp[] = array($parts[$i], $parts[$i+1]);
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($tmp);
echo "</pre>";
```

You might want to make sure it is an even number. (check $nr).

Edit: OP says you have some empty elements in the array $parts.

I don't know what causes that, possibly some encoding issues, not sure without having the original material (string).
A wild guess: Try to utf8_decode the original string, then do the preg_replace, and then print_r.
Like this:

```
$longstring = "randomstring1 1001     randomstring2 205 randomstring3 58";
$longstring = utf8_decode($longstring);
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $longstring);
$parts = explode(" ",$str);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($parts);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: So far this answer has given me the best results. All the strings and numbers are nicely grouped together as [6] => Array ( [0] => str, [1] => num ) but there remain a few which report empty values [7] => Array
        ( [0] => [1] => ) .

Comment: Is it the last one that is empty, or is it somewhere in the middle of the output-array?

Comment: Between every group of strings and numbers and also a few at the end of the output array

Comment: I made a mistake, somehow used ! instead of / in the preg. Try the updated version in my post. This line: $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $longstring);

Comment: No change :/ It's quite a weird string to be honest.

Comment: I have tried a couple of answers from other posts that mention array_filter, but no luck yet...

Comment: Does the string contain stuff like \t \n in it? That is considered a match for \s in the regex. You can also debug yourself by doing a print_r($parts).

Comment: var_dump or print_r ($tmp[1]) gives me this: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) ""
  [1]=>
  string(7) ""
}. It seems that there these 'empty' elements contain only whitespace

Comment: Recent tests show that string(5) "" doesn't contain whitespace, then what could it be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96245/discussion-between-beeelze-and-erwin-moller).

Answer (score 1):

explode string and then check it like this

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/AgC4Ty)

```
$str="randomstring number     randomstring number     randomstring number";
$exp=explode(" ",$str);
for($i=0;$i<count($exp);$i++)
{
    if(trim($exp[$i])=="")
        continue;
    $result[]=array(0=>$exp[$i],1=>$exp[$i+1]);
    $i++;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
//Our string
$string = "randomstring 11     randomstring 22     randomstring 33";

//Split them up if they have MORE THAN ONE space
$firstSplit = preg_split('/\s\s+/', $string);

//Set up a new array to contain them
$newArray = array();

//For each of the ones like "randomstring 11"
foreach($firstSplit as $key => $split){

    //Split them if they have ONE OR MORE space
    $secondSplit = preg_split('/\s+/', $split);

    //Add them to the array
    //Note: change this part to structure the array however you'd like
    $newArray[$key]["string"] = $secondSplit[0];
    $newArray[$key]["integer"] = $secondSplit[1];
}
```

The comments should explain well enough what is happening here, it will leave you with the following:

```
array (size=3)
    0 => 
      array (size=2)
        'string' => string 'randomstring' (length=12)
        'integer' => string '11' (length=2)
    1 => 
      array (size=2)
        'string' => string 'randomstring' (length=12)
        'integer' => string '22' (length=2)
    2 => 
      array (size=2)
        'string' => string 'randomstring' (length=12)
        'integer' => string '33' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the shortest way but i would say your issue can be consist of this steps

1- convert the multi spaces to one space

2- explode the big string to one array has all the sub string

3- group the elements by loop over the big array

```
<?php
$str = 'randomstring1 number1     randomstring2 number2     randomstring3 number3';
//remove the spaces and put all the element in one array
$arr  = explode(' ', $str);
$space = array('');
$arr = array_values(array_diff($arr, $space));

//now loop over the array and group elements
$result = $temArr = array();
foreach($arr as $index => $element){
  if($index % 2){//second element (number)
    $temArr[] =  $element;
    $result[] = $temArr;
    $temArr = array();
  }else{//first element (randomstring)
    $temArr[] =  $element;
  }
}

//print the result
var_dump($result);die;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First split by 2 or more spaces, then split those groups by the single space.
Try this:

```
$input  = 'randomstring1 number1     randomstring2 number2     randomstring3 number3';
$groups = preg_split("/[\s]{2,}/", $input );
$result = array_map(function($i){
    return explode(' ', $i);
}, $groups);
```

Which gets me this result:

```
array(3) {
    [0] = array(2) {
        [0] = string(13) "randomstring1"
        [1] = string(7) "number1"
    }
    [1] = array(2) {
        [0] = string(13) "randomstring2"
        [1] = string(7) "number2"
    }
    [2] = array(2) {
        [0] = string(13) "randomstring3"
        [1] = string(7) "number3"
    }
}
```